# calling a prototype function repeats the wrong function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn about structures and anonymous functions in JavaScript and I had a looked at a lot codes or libraries who have done it this way. However when i try to follow the way they do it, it seems to call the wrong innit. Here is my code:

file 1: is called startUp;

```
this.project = this.project || {};

(function(){

    project.init = function (){
        console.log("startUp");
         project.Setup();

    }

}());
```

file 2: is called Setup

```
this.project = this.project || {};

(function() {

    var Setup = function() {
        this.init();
    };

    var p = Setup.prototype;

    p.init = function() {
        console.log("Setup");
    };

    project.Setup = Setup;
}());
```

for some reason the innit in the setup isn't being called but the start up innit is looping like crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `Setup`, `this` is not what you think it is.  `this` is set by how the function is called.

So when you do `project.Setup();`, the value of `this` inside `Setup` is `project`.  So `this.init()` is calling `project.int()`.  Which is calling `project.Setup();` and so on, creating an infinite loop.

`Setup.prototype.init` will only be called if you do `new Setup`.

Comment: Just a note `new Setup` really isn't the solution here.  I was just trying to explain how `this` (and `new`) worked.

Comment: Oh right, but it seems to do the right job for me. Cheers anyways